# On the vector bundles associated to the eigenspaces of an almost complex structure.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, almost-complex

Let $(M,J)$ be an almost complex manifold, that is $M$ is a smooth differentiable manifold of even dimension and $J$ is an endomorphism of the tangent vector bundle $TM$ such that $J^2=-\textrm{id}_{TM}$.

Let $T^{\mathbb{C}}M$ be the complexification of $TM$, that is:
$$T^{\mathbb{C}}M:=TM\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}=TM\oplus iTM,$$
where the tensor product is done fiber by fiber. Then, the endomorphism $J$ is diagonalizable on each fiber. Let $T^{(1,0)}M$, respectively $T^{(0,1)}M$ be the disjoint union of eigenspaces associated with $+i$, respectively $-i$. For example, one has:
$$T^{(1,0)}M:=\coprod_{x\in M}E_i(J_{\vert T_x^{\mathbb{C}}M}).$$

> Why are $T^{(1,0)}M$ and $T^{(0,1)}M$ vector bundles?

Roughly speaking, why the vector space structure of $E_{\pm i}(J_{\vert T_x^\mathbb{C}M})$ depends continuously on $x$?

More generally the following question arises:

> **Question.** Let $\xi$ be a vector bundle and let $F$ be an endomorphism of $\xi$, when is $\ker(F)$ a vector bundle?

It seems that the question is non-empty since the dimension of $\ker(F_{\vert E_b})$ can change with the point $b\in B$, where $p\colon E\rightarrow B$ is the projection of $\xi$, which obviously prevents $\ker(F)$ from being a vector bundle.

Any enlightenment will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer to your main question is always, provided you include the hypothesis that $F:\xi \to \xi$ has constant rank.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163759/kernel-of-a-constant-rank-bundle-map-using-the-constant-rank-theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the special case of $T^{1,0}M$ and $T^{0,1}M$, there is a simple direct argument: Given a local frame $\{v_j\}$ for $TM$, the sections $v_j-iJ(v_j)$ form a local frame for $T^{1,0}M$ and the sections $v_j+iJ(v_j)$ form a local frame for $T^{0,1}M$. So you get local trivializations for the bundles.

As stated in the comment by @Andrew, in the general setting (which even works for bundle maps between different bundles over the same manifold which have the identity as their base map), the only condition for $\text{ker}(F)$ being a smooth subbundle is that the rank is constant. To prove this, it is easier to first show that $\text{im}(F)$ is a smooth subbundle. Given $x\in M$, choose elements $v_1(x),\dots,v_k(x)\in E_x$ for which the images under $F$ form a basis for $F(E_x)$. Extending them arbitrarily to local sections defined on a neighbourhood of $x$, the images under $F$ are linearly independent in a (possibly smaller) neighbourhood of $x$. Since the rank is constant, they have to form a local frame on this neighbourhood.

Having this at hand, you can choose a basis $\{\tilde v_{k+1}(x),\dots,\tilde v_n(x)\}$ of $\text{ker}(F_x)$ and again extend to local sections $\tilde v_j$ arbitrarily. By assumption, $F(\tilde v_j)$ is a smooth linear combination of $F(v_1),\dots,F(v_k)$ for each $j=k+1,\dots,n$. If you subtract the corresponding multiples of $v_1,\dots,v_k$ from $\tilde v_j$ you get a smooth section $v_j$ of $\text{ker}(F)$. Since the resulting sections are linearly independent in $x$, they are linearly independent on a neighbourhood of $x$ and thus define a local frame.

Comment: I have an issue with your first paragraph - your argument only shows that $T^{1,0}M$ and $T^{0,1}M$ form real vector bundles isomorphic to $TM$, right?

However, if I want to prove that they form complex subbundles of $T^{\mathbb{C}}M$, I still have to resort to proving that bundle maps $J_{\mathbb{C}} \pm Id_{T^{\mathbb{C}}M}$ have a constant rank, is that true? By $J_{\mathbb{C}}$ I mean a complexification of the original endomorphism $J$.

Comment: This is a simple direct computation: $i(v-iJ(v))=J(v)+iv=J(v)-iJ(J(v))$ and similarly for the anti-holomorphic part. So the constant rank statement is true.

Comment: Sure I can see that fibers of $T^{1,0}M$ and $T^{0,1}M$ are complex subspaces. I can also see why they have a constant rank. What I was asking is that in any case, one always has to use the "constant rank means subbundle" statement in some form, your first paragraph is not enough to prove that they they are complex subbundles of a (complex) rank $\frac{1}{2} \dim(M)$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not sure that I understand the quesitons. You can write real and complex local frames, so you get real and complex subbundles. (You just need that the $v_i$ are a real or complex basis of one tengent space extended arbitrarly, then they will form a local real or complex frame locally around that point.)

Comment: I am sorry for asking a confusing question. In the first paragraph of your answer, you say that for $T^{1,0}M$ and $T^{0,1}M$, it is easy to find the local frame directly. I agree with you if you want to prove that they are real vector (sub)bundles.

If you want to find the complex local frame, you have to extend some complex basis of the fiber (as you say) - but to prove that this is actually a local frame around that point, you need to know that the rank of the fibers of $T^{1,0}M$ is constant.

I was just asking if I this line of thought is correct.

Comment: The construction can be done for both summands simultaneously. Then you get sections lying in one of the subbundles that together form a frame for $T_{\mathbb C}M$. Since the bundles evidently intersect trivially, you get constant rank as a consequnece.. I don't see a need to observe constant rank in advance. But the constant rank statement is anyway obvous from point-wise considerations, so I am not sure whether it makes a lot of difference whether you use it or not.